# Creating Calender event using Xamarin Android(7.0) c# Error with creating event

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Hi I am trying to debug a problem here and really struggling.

```
ContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues();
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.CalendarId, -1);
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title, title);
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Description, desc);
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart, GetDateTimeMS(year, month, day, starthr, startmin));
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtend, GetDateTimeMS(year, month, day, stophr, stopmin));
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.HasAlarm, true);
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventTimezone, "Local");
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventEndTimezone, "Local");
        //  eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.AllowedReminders, true);
        var eventUri = ContentResolver.Insert(CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri, eventValues);
        long eventID = long.Parse(eventUri.LastPathSegment);
        ContentValues reminderValues = new ContentValues();
        reminderValues.Put(CalendarContract.Reminders.InterfaceConsts.CalendarId, -1);
        reminderValues.Put(CalendarContract.Reminders.InterfaceConsts.EventId, eventID);
        reminderValues.Put(
              CalendarContract.Reminders.InterfaceConsts.Method,
              (int)RemindersMethod.Alert
            );
        reminderValues.Put(CalendarContract.Reminders.InterfaceConsts.Minutes, 5);
```

It crashes out at this line:
var eventUri = ContentResolver.Insert(CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri, eventValues);

with the error :
Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.android.calendar/calendars/-1

Im testing on a Samsung Galaxy Edge G925F

Answer (score 0):

Ok the answer was pritty simple.

1. I had not specified a sensible CalendarId the default for most androids is 1 or 3. I would use 3 because on some models 1 is reserved for birthday events. (unless its a birthday you want..)
2. The date formatter has been doing things a little wrong. Instead of specifiying a month, the JSON pull event was removing leading 0's hence making 09 just 9. This was causing issues so just went ahead and put a if statement and specified the month explicitly.

   ```
   long GetDateTimeMS(int yr, int month, int day, int hr, int min)
   {
       Java.Util.Calendar c = Java.Util.Calendar.GetInstance(Java.Util.TimeZone.Default);

       c.Set(Java.Util.Calendar.DayOfMonth,day);
       c.Set(Java.Util.Calendar.HourOfDay, hr);
       c.Set(Java.Util.Calendar.Minute, min);
       if (month == 1)
       {
           c.Set(Java.Util.Calendar.Month, Java.Util.Calendar.January);
       }
       else if (month == 2)
       {
           c.Set(Java.Util.Calendar.Month, Java.Util.Calendar.February);
       }
       else if (month == 3)
       {
           c.Set(Java.Util.Calendar.Month, Java.Util.Calendar.March);
       }
       else if (month == 4)
       {
           c.Set(Java.Util.Calendar.Month, Java.Util.Calendar.April);
       }
       else if (month == 5)
       {
           c.Set(Java.Util.Calendar.Month, Java.Util.Calendar.May);
       }
       else if (month == 6)
       {
           c.Set(Java.Util.Calendar.Month, Java.Util.Calendar.June);
       }
       else if (month == 7)
       {
           c.Set(Java.Util.Calendar.Month, Java.Util.Calendar.July);
       }
       else if (month == 8)
       {
           c.Set(Java.Util.Calendar.Month, Java.Util.Calendar.August);
       }
       else if (month == 9)
       {
           c.Set(Java.Util.Calendar.Month, Java.Util.Calendar.September);
       }
       else if (month == 10)
       {
           c.Set(Java.Util.Calendar.Month, Java.Util.Calendar.October);
       }
       else if (month == 11)
       {
           c.Set(Java.Util.Calendar.Month, Java.Util.Calendar.November);
       }
       else if (month == 12)
       {
           c.Set(Java.Util.Calendar.Month, Java.Util.Calendar.December);
       }
       c.Set(Java.Util.Calendar.Year,yr);

       return c.TimeInMillis;
   }
   ```

I hope that helps others out of a jam.

Comment: Just a note I am sure their is a more productive way of doing this.